# Weigh the percentages based on the number of inhabitants

Tags: weights, weighted-data

I am analyzing the diffusion of a service in some regions. Is there a legitimate criterion for weighing percentages by the number of inhabitants? I would like to "improve" the results of the most populated regions. A schematic example of the values ​​I'm dealing with is:

| Region | % of households with access to fiber-optic communications | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Region 1 | 70 | 5000000 |
| Region 2 | 90 | 500000 |
| Region 3 | 75 | 750000 |
| Region 4 | 75 | 10000000 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: If you want the overall percentage, then your calculation will be the average of the regional percentages weighted by regional populations

Comment: So, assuming the total population is 100000000, the "adjusted" % for Region 1 would be 70 * 5000000 / 100000000?

Comment: I would not describe it that way but instead that the total %  is $\dfrac{70\%\times 5000000 + 90\%\times 500000+ 75\% \times 750000 \cdots}{5000000+500000+750000 +\cdots}$

Comment: Let T be the total %. So the % for Region 1 would be 70 * 5000000 / T? Perhaps this would penalize too much regions with few inhabitants.